# Isabelle: Power of a matrix (A^n)?

Tags: matrix, isabelle

There is a matrix multiplication definition in `Cartesian_Euclidean_Space` (in directory HOL/Multivariate_Analysis"):

```
definition matrix_matrix_mult :: "('a::semiring_1) ^'n^'m ⇒ 'a ^'p^'n ⇒ 'a ^ 'p ^'m"
    (infixl "**" 70)
  where "m ** m' == (χ i j. setsum (λk. ((m$i)$k) * ((m'$k)$j)) (UNIV :: 'n set)) ::'a ^ 'p ^'m"
```

Now the the squared matrix would be `A ** A` and A^3 would be `A ** A ** A`.

I couldn't find a powerfunction, to define `A^n`  (i.e., `A ** A ** ... ** A` n times).

Is there a power function in the library? Is a manual definition needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following definition in `HOL/Power.thy` :

```
primrec power :: "'a ⇒ nat ⇒ 'a" (infixr "^" 80) where
    power_0: "a ^ 0 = 1"
  | power_Suc: "a ^ Suc n = a * a ^ n"
```

(Control + Click gets you to the respecitve definition! So I clicked on "^", I just wrote "1 ^ 1 = 1" as a lemma first.

Here is the definition for the power of a matrice.
(As I only use square matrices this is fine, but a more general type of `^'n^'m` would be nice.)

```
primrec powerM :: "(('a::semiring_1) ^'n^'n) ⇒ nat ⇒ (('a::semiring_1) ^'n^'n)" 
(infixr "^^^" 80) where
  powerM_0: "A ^^^(0::nat) = mat 1"
| powerM_Suc: "A ^^^(Suc n) = A ** (powerM A n)"
```